# UIView category for setting origins and sizes directly

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, categories

I am a beginner of iPhone app programing.
I really don't like the way we have to set origins and sizes like:

```
UIView *view;  
CGRect frame = view.frame;  
frame.origin.x = 100;  
view.frame = frame;
```

or:

```
UIView *view;  
view.frame = CGRectMake(100, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
```

so I created a category for UIView like:

```
@interface UIView (Origin)  
-(void) setOriginX:(CGFloat)x;  
-(void) setOriginY:(CGFloat)y;  
-(void) setOriginX:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y;  
-(void) setWidth:(CGFloat)w;  
-(void) setHeight:(CGFloat)h;  
-(void) setWidth:(CGFloat)w height:(CGFloat)h;  
@end  

@implementation UIView(Origin)  
-(void) setOriginX:(CGFloat)x {  
  self.frame = CGRectMake(x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);  
}  
...  
@end
```

then I could write:

```
UIView *view;  
[view setOriginX 100];
```

this is much convenient for me, but is there any concern that i shouldn't do such thing, or any easier way to set origins/sizes directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find a few shortcuts for setting frame [defined in three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UI/Headers/UIViewAdditions.h) really convenient for positioning and resizing views, like:

```
// frame.origin.x
x
// frame.origin.y
y
//frame.origin
origin
// center
center
// frame.size
size
// center.x
centerX
// center.y
centerY
// frame.size.width
width
// frame.size.height
height
// x
left
// x + width
right
// y
top
// y + height
bottom
```

They all have setters and getters defined.